# Return date format in 2 rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

I have this date format : `hh tt`, returns for example: 12 AM or 07 PM to whom ever isn't familiar with that.

I'm trying to find a way to return this result in 2 rows using only the date time format.
I've tried something like `hh \n tt`, `hh <br/ tt`.
\n returns the n (but skip a row between the number and time of the day.)
`<br/>` breaks the entire function and throws an exception.
If you have another creative solution, it will be good as well.
I don't want solutions like `.subString (0,2) + <br/> + substring(3,5)` or familiar.
Thanks a lot

result is supposed to be like:

```
12
pm
```

this is my entire code for this :

```
SingleDayStat.mDisplayDate = String.Format((DateTimeUtils.DateTimeToFormat(DateUtil.HourReset(temp_datetime, TimeOffset), LibraryUtils.GetStatisticsGraphsDateFormatForDay()).ToLowerInvariant()), "<br/>");


public static string DateTimeToFormat(DateTime Date, string Format)
    {
        return Date.ToString(Format);
    }
 public static string GetStatisticsGraphsDateFormatForDay()
    {
        string format = string.Empty;
        format = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StatisticsGraphsDateFormatForDay"];
        return format;
    }
<add key="StatisticsGraphsDateFormatForDay" value="hh{0}tt"/>
```

HourReset Method only rounds the hour to the nearest round hour

Comment: ofc.. suppose to be like 12 (row skip) pm.

Comment: Please post the code, both the code-behind and the HTML code into which you are trying to inject the string. As is, we can only guess at what you are saying. Perhaps you are trying to generate HTML, perhaps not

Comment: `time.ToString("hh\ntt")` works fine to me

Comment: Try, please, "hh \r\n tt" (Windows prone to accept \r\n but not \n). I've succeeded with "hh \r\n tt" on WinForms

Comment: `DateTime.ToString("hh\ntt")` is a perfectly valid way of doing this - if it's not working for you you're not doing what you say you're doing.

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("hh tt") returns 11 - so that is culture specific, did you know?

Comment: How are you trying to output this? Console, Textbox, Webpage, MessageBox... this is likely to affect the answer.

Comment: \n not works for me, i told that..

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToString("hh \n\r<\br> tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) works for me

Comment: Updated Question to fully show my code.

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael What exception are you getting when you format "<br />" into the string? It should (and does) work absolutely fine. You must be doing something funky elsewhere.

Comment: @AntP this is no else where :), anything you see its what i return from server

Comment: So what exception are you getting?

Comment: im not getting exception when im using string.format, its just not working, im getting an exception when i place <br/> in the date format

Comment: **What exception are you getting?**

Comment: dunno who downvoted my question almost 1 year after i asked it, but it wasn't nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can get you covered:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(FormatTime(DateTime.Now, false));
    Console.WriteLine(FormatTime(DateTime.Now, true ));
    Console.WriteLine(FormatTime(DateTime.Now, "'"  ));
    Console.WriteLine(FormatTime(DateTime.Now, "<hr />"));
}

static string FormatTime(DateTime date, bool isHtml)
{
    return FormatTime(date, isHtml ? "<br />" : Environment.NewLine);
}

static string FormatTime(DateTime date, string separator)
{
    return date.ToString(String.Format("hh'{0}'tt",
              separator.Replace("'", "\\'")), new CultureInfo("EN-US"));
}
```

Output:

```
08
AM
08<br />AM
08<hr />AM
08'AM
```

This method is a improvement over Sriram answer, as correctly escapes your string separator. This way you can use a `<hr />` separator and it will be presented as expected, instead of `12<12r />AM`

Answer (score 1):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
string formatted = now.ToString(string.Format("hh{0}tt",Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, replacing `Environment.NewLine` with break tag won't work?

Comment: Have to vote this down as it either won't work or is completely unnecessary, depending on specifics of the question that aren't yet clear (which in itself is a good reason not to answer at all).

Comment: @AntP I don't think this answer deserves downvote! If question is about formatting it as html them replacing `Environment.NewLine` with `<br>` should be enough.

Comment: @AntP: This is the solution. Your \n is bad!

Comment: well, even doing like that returns to me for example : 04{0}am , not replacing anything in the string.format for some reason.

Comment: Show that on screenshot (show code in VS and output - set breakpoint or sth). You are doing something weird.

Comment: @Peri Haters gonna hate no matter what the quality of answer is :(

Comment: This is exactly my point - it makes no difference whether he uses "\n" in a string literal or formats in `Environment.NewLine`, that's clearly *not the problem*. As @Peri says, he is *doing something weird* because what he says he's doing in the OP is already valid - the actual problem is not yet clear as is obvious to anyone who as read the question properly. This answer is redundant.

Comment: @AntP If question is not clear the go ahead and downvote the question or ask for clarification if you need, not to downvote an answer which really doesn't deserve it. This is what I understood and given an answer. If OP says this is not what he needs, well am happy to revise my answer!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel The answer *does* deserve it because it doesn't address the problem. It may address what you *thought* was the problem but misinterpreting the question leads to bad answers.

Answer (score 0):

ASPX

```
<div ID="ltlTime" runat="server"></div>
```

Code Behind

```
DateTime curDate  = DateTime.Now;
string formatted = curDate.ToString("hh tt").Replace(" ","<BR>"); // to render in html
ltlTime.InnerHtml = formatted
```